# error compilacion unity script flappy bird

Tags: c#, unity

> Assets/Scripts/Bird.cs(21,8): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `t'
>   error en t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Timers;
public class Bird : MonoBehaviour {
    // Movement speed
    public float speed = 1;


    // Flap force
    public float force = 100;

    public double Interval = 10000;

    private Timer t;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Fly towards the right
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
        t = new Timer(Interval)
        t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
        t.Start();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // Flap
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * force);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        // Restart
        t.Stop();
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

    private static void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            ///
            /// aqui pones el codigo para mostrar que gano
            ///
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error sintáctico, y es que te falta el `;` en la declaración del `new Timer`:

```
void Start () {
    // Fly towards the right
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
    t = new Timer(Interval)   //<------
    t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: me sigue dando el mismo error :(

Comment: @kit Ya te edité la respuesta

Comment: Gracias, ahora me da otro error, que hago, creo una nueva pregunta? o paso por aquí este nuevo error " Assets/Scripts/Bird.cs(40,13): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `Bird.t'
 ",  es en la linea     t.Stop();

Comment: @kit Si, si es un error diferente debes crear otra pregunta